# bunch of sendmail processes stuck in "DATA" mode

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I admin a small mail server for an organization. Starting on the weekend there have been intermittent email issues. Apparently incoming emails were not being delivered (e.g. from google to our server).

After examining the logs, I saw the reason why mail has been spotty:

```
sendmail[1234] rejecting connections on daemon MTA-blah: 15 children, max 15
```

So sendmail reached the MAX_DAEMON_CHILDREN limit.

Looking at processes list I saw a bunch of sendmail processes sitting in DATA mode for hours.

```
sendmail: blah2345345 xxx.mail.gq1.yahoo.com [216.39.60.xxx]: DATA
sendmail: blah3345345 yyy.mail.gq1.yahoo.com [216.39.60.xxx]: DATA
```

I can't find any mention of email id (like blah2345345) in the logs.

Any insight as to what's going on? Only connections from Yahoo servers are stalling in DATA mode.

Thanks!

Edit:
This is a problem with **incoming** mail. /var/spool/mqueue is empty. Sendmail is v8.14.x

Comment: Can you send email to yahoo without problems? [Messages bigger than 10KB]

Comment: Yes, I can send mail to yahoo just fine. With or without attachments.

Comment: I'd suggest collecting a packet capture so you can raw SMTP communication between the various hosts.

Answer (score 0):

To forcibly send the mail from mail queue use the below given command

> sendmail -q -v

What is the sendmail version

Comment: You talk about **outgoing** connections. As I understand problem is with **incoming** connections.

Comment: Andrzej, you are correct. There is a bunch of incoming connections that are sitting in DATA mode for hours. Mainly from yahoo's servers. Sendmail is v8.14.x

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fixes you may:

- use iptables (firewall) to limit number of connections from the trouble making network (e.g. to 5)
- lower Timeout.datablock from default 1h towards minimum required by RFC (3m)
  http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/op-sh-4.html